# Unit testing using testthat for R packages with compiled code

Tags: c, r

I am currently developing an R package where most of the computational work is done in C code. In particular, I have several complex C routines for which I then wrap with an R function. These I know I can test using testthat because the namespace includes the C function called (I am using roxygen comments to generate the namespace).

The difficulty I am having is that some of these C routines have a few complicated subroutines, the output of which is non-trivial to check. These functions are never called from R directly, so there is no code in my R/ directory that has a roxygen comment that results in the namespace making these functions available. What I want to do is write an R routine that performs the same computation and then use testthat to compare against the output of the C function. I have done this and it works great when I load the entire shared library (using dyn.load), but I don't think this is the proper approach for tests in a package that I intend to submit to CRAN.

My current workaround is to create a dummy function in a file in my R/ directory that then has a roxygen comment for each of the functions I wish to load. That way when I run devtools::document(), these functions are included in the namespace.

Is this the best approach, or is there another method that is better/preferred?

Comment: It's not uncommon for people to omit some tests when submitting to CRAN. Eg anything involving multicore/multithreaded compute is limited by the fact that CRAN limits you to 2 threads. There's nothing stopping you running any tests you want offline, and limiting the CRAN tests only to the R functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the reply -- my concern was that not having tests for some of these subroutines would cause an issue with the submission being accepted to CRAN as the portion of my code most likely to have a bug in it are these subroutines that are never called directly from R

Comment: To follow up, if I want to run these tests locally and want to be able to run them from R studio with all my other testthat unit tests, is the approach I mentioned in my post the best one to accomplish that? Or is there a better one that I am unaware of?